# re: UTF-8, PHP and XML Mysql

Tags: php, vim, encoding, utf-8

This is relating to [UTF-8, PHP and XML Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791082/utf-8-php-and-xml-mysql), which I am still trying to get my head around.

I Have a couple of separate questions that will hopefully help me understand how to resolve the issues I am having.

I am trying to read values from a database and output into a file in UTF-8 format. But I am having encoding issues, so i thought I would strip back all my code ans start with:

```
$string = "Otivägen";
// then output to a file.
```

But in `vim` i cant even enter the that string, every time I paste it in I get `OtivÃ¤gen`

I tried to create a blank PHP file with only that string and upload it, but when I `cat` the file again I get `OtivÃ¤gen`.

My questions are ...

1. Why is `vim` displaying it like
   this?
2. If the file is downloaded would it
   display correctly if an application
   was expecting UTF-8?
3. How can I output this string into a
   file that will eventually be an XML
   file in UTF-8 encoding.

My understanding of encoding is limited at the moment, and I am trying to understand it.

Comment: Which version of VIM are you using? Can your terminal show the ä character?

Comment: what is your locale? (output of `locale` in terminal?) it might helph if you switch your whole system to a UTF-8 locale. Although that will give you a mess with all non-UTF-8 filenames :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of confusion associated with encodings in Vim.  There are two encoding settings, `'encoding'` and `'fileencoding'`.

`'encoding'` is the one that relates to the current vim session - I leave this as 'utf-8' all the time, but then I only use gVim or unicode-enabled terminals.

`'fileencoding'` is the encoding of the file itself, which is automatically detected or can be overridden with a setting (`++enc`) or a modeline I believe.  It is detected based on the `'fileencodings'` option.

Try this:

```
vim
:set encoding=utf-8
:e ++enc=utf-8 test_file.php
i
$string = "Otiv<Ctrl-K>a:gen";
:w
```

For more information, see:

```
:help 'encoding'
:help 'fileencoding'
:help 'fileencodings'
:help ++enc
:help modeline
```

See also http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Encoding

Comment: I tried: gvim ++enc=utf-8 test.me "-bash: gvim: command not found"
so I then tried:
vim ++enc=utf-8 test.me "test.me" 1L, 23C
Error detected while processing command line:
E492: Not an editor command: +enc=utf-8

What am i mising?

Comment: I suspect that your Vim is not compiled with multi-byte support.  What does `:echo has('multi_byte')` say?  If it's not '1', then you've almost certainly not got a unicode enabled vim, so you'll need to either install another one or compile it yourself.  Neither of these is difficult: which OS?

Comment: :echo has('multi_byte'). It does output 1

Comment: Oops, my bad: I was abusing ++enc.  Try the edited instructions above.

Comment: Still no luck! I really hate `encoding`/`fileencoding`!

Answer (score 1):

1. Vim supports UTF-8 [from version 6.0](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html). Your system is likely not using UTF-8 by default - you're likely seeing UTF-8 text displayed in ASCII (or another 8-bit fixed encoding).
2. It should. Set the encoding on the file to UTF-8 when you serve it.
3. Any file writing function would accept this - UTF-8 is just a sequence of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a vim issue - if your terminal software is not set to utf-8 then you'll see the above issues regardless of what vim is doing.